# Página HTML com dois idiomas

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, sou iniciante no mundo do desenvolvimento web e gostaria de ajuda para realizar a concepção de um pequeno projeto que estou estudando.
    O projeto deve conter apenas uma página e eu gostaria de saber a forma mais simples de colocar dois idiomas para o usuário escolher. No caso a página padrão seria em inglês, mas teria um botão ou algo do tipo para que o usuário colocasse o site em português.
    É preciso usar outra linguagem como PHP ou JavaScript, ou com o HTML e CSS puro dá pra fazer?

O link abaixo leva para a página do código, também estou utilizando bootstrap:

https://codepen.io/mrfelps/pen/mByWKG

Comment: Tenter dar mais detalhes para que o possamos ajudar, exemplo de código que tem já feito ou se vai crirar o site de raiz.. se vai usar wordpress?

Comment: Você já criou algum código? Não espere que alguem faça o código para você. Seja mais específico. Veja o [tour] para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Sim, acabei de editar a pergunta rsrs, estou aprendendo a usar a ferramenta ainda, aos poucos. Na edição incluí o link com o código. Abs.

Comment: @FelipeBraz Coloque o código aqui mesmo, imagine se o site que você passou o link com o sei código estiver fora do ar ou for deletado? O ideal é você colocar o código aqui mesmo, dessa maneira o site fica mais organizado e mais fácil para outros que enfrentarem o mesmo problema.

Comment: @RORSCHACH Entendi, peço desculpas pois não consegui colocar o link por aqui. Ainda não tive tempo de entender todas as funcionalidades do Stack, mas a ideia é justamente aprender e ir além (-:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem um [tópico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369947/multi-language-php-script) que foi respondido, utilizando PHP:

Etapa 1: configure uma estrutura de árvore de pastas como esta:

```
Linguagens
 -en
   -lang.en.php
 -fr
   -lang.fr.php
 -de
   -lang.de.php
```

**continue fazendo novas pastas com todos os outros idiomas que você deseja.**

Passo 2: Crie uma pasta com os arquivos de idioma, exemplo: `linguagens/en/lang.en.php`

```
<?php   
  $lang['label']      = 'Value for this label';
  $lang['firstname']  = 'First Name';
  $lang['lastname']   = 'Last Name';
  $lang['phone']      = 'Phone';       
  // ETC
?>
```

Você repetiria isso para qualquer outro idioma, por exemplo, `linguagens/fr/lang.fr.php`. NOTA sempre depois da `$lang` os nomes permanecem iguais em inglês.

```
<?php   
  $lang['label']      = 'Valeur pour ce label';
  $lang['firstname']  = 'Prénom';
  $lang['lastname']   = 'Nom de famille';
  $lang['phone']      = 'Téléphone';       
  // ETC
?>
```

Etapa 3: Verifique se o usuário solicitou uma alteração de idioma, por meio de uma variável url.

```
<?php
  // Start a Session, You might start this somewhere else already.
  session_start();

  // What languages do we support
  $available_langs = array('en','fr','de');

  // Set our default language session
  $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';   

  if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] != ''){ 
    // check if the language is one we support
    if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $available_langs))
    {       
      $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang']; // Set session
    }
  }
  // Include active language
  include('linguagens/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');

?>
```

Etapa 4: você pode acessar suas partes de idioma assim e mudaria com base no arquivo de idioma carregado.

```
<?php
  echo $lang['firstname'];
?>
```